# How can I increase the height of a scrollable tabpanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a form in Visual Studio which has a `TabControl` with several `TabPage` objects on it.  I want one `TabPage` to fit content that is several times too big vertically for the object in the Visual Studio designer (and indeed would be too big for the monitor).  *How can I increase the size of the `TabPage` beyond that of its parent `TabControl` or `Form`, so that I can add the required controls?*

When I try to edit the height of the `TabPage` object in the Properties window, it just undoes my edit.

Comment: You Can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.itemsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @PradnyaBolli Increasing the ItemSize makes the tabs with the labels on at the top go taller, I don't want that

Comment: Set the TabPage's AutoScroll property to True.

Comment: @LarsTech yes I have done that and if I place a control just on the very bottom edge of the TabPage in the editor it gives me a vertical scroll bar.  But there is no way to increase the size of the TabPage beyond that of its enclosing TabControl, so that I can scroll down in the editor and add more controls.

Comment: Try putting all your stuff into a UserControl and then when you add the UserControl to the TabPage, you can set the height of the control yourself.  The TagPage would still do the scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the AutoScroll property of the TabPanel to true (thanks @LarsTech).
2. Add a user control to the TabPanel.
3. Move the user control far down the TabPanel.  You can do this by changing its Location x value.

After (3) the scroll bar will change in the editor and the editable area of the tab panel will have increased